# Insert Vertex into Polyline based on Point layer using arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, topology, vertices

This is essentially the same question asked [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54128/how-to-insert-vertex-in-polyline-layer-where-we-have-a-point-in-a-point-layer) that was not answered...

Using ArcGIS 10.1 Advanced

I have a point layer with points that represent the intersection of a driveway with a street centerline.  There is not always a vertex on the street centerline where the driveway intersects, so I am looking for a solution (preferably using arcpy) that loops through each point and inserts a vertex on the line that intersects with that point.  I do not want to use [Split Line at Point](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003w000000) method because I don't want to split the line. Looking for any ideas on how to accomplish this...

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty solution that does not utilize scripting would be to import your polyline and point layers into a geodatabase, create a [topology with the "Must Be Covered By Line" rule](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t000000sp000000.htm), and validate topology.  The check will insert vertices at intersections where they do not already exist.

Comment: I like this answer if:  this is all you need to do with python and you're not integrating this into a larger python tool suite; and since you have the "Advanced" license.  Why not use and rock a topology.

Comment: The only problem with this is that it would insert vertices into places where I don't want them, such as at overpasses/underpasses...